# pass selected value from drop down list in updateParameters(self) as input to python script

Tags: geoprocessing, parameters, validation

I managed to create two drop down lists using the validation code where an user  can select the first parameter from a list and get another filtered list for the second parameter.

However, I am struggling with the passing the selected second parameter as an input to the python script.

```
def updateParameters(self):
"""Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
has been changed."""

accounts = "Database Connections\\someDatabase.sde\\TableToFilter"
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(accounts)
self.params[0].filter.list = sorted(list(set(row.getValue('USERID1') for row in rows)))

if self.params[0].altered:
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(accounts, """ "USERID1" = '""" + self.params[0].value + "'")
    accountList = sorted(list(set(row.getValue('ACCGRPNAME') for row in rows)))
    self.params[1].filter.list = accountList
    self.params[1] = self.params[1].value

#del rows
return
```

I am using self.params[1] = self.params[1].value to pass the selected value to the rest of the script but I'm not sure I am doing the right thing.

How would you retrieve the selected value and pass it to the script?